# PHP doesn't see 2 equal strings

Tags: php

So I'm busy on a verification system, when the player of the game puts a sentence in his/her status, in this case: `HT-N5I4-S3ZI-GU6A` and my script checks if it's the same one as the code in my db. If it is, its proven to be their account. Because I've experienced that people make accounts under fake names.

When I echo the code in my db, it echoes:
`HT-N5I4-S3ZI-GU6A`

And the one in my test players mission echoes:
`HT-N5I4-S3ZI-GU6A`

It is exactly the same code, but when I wanna compare them like this:

```
    if($_SESSION['user']['email_activation'] == $functions->getMotto($_SESSION['user']['username']))
    {
        echo "Works";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Doesnt work";
    }
```

It aways echoes 'doesn\'t work'. Did I use the wrong equalization operator? Or any other mistakes?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there are no non-printable characters somewhere (newlines, spaces, etc.)?

Comment: Do `var_dump()`'s instead of `echo`'s.

Comment: And yes, you should use `===` instead of `==` or else something like `0 == 'a string'` would evaluate to `true`

Comment: echo bin2hex($string1)." ".bin2hex($string2); and compare

Comment: Humour us: `var_dump(md5($_SESSION['user']['email_activation']))` and `var_dump(md5($functions->getMotto($_SESSION['user']['username'])))`

Comment: No, you just dont have the same values in the variables.

Comment: It's definitely a problem with the values themselves, the two strings, no matter how many hyphens they have, are equal.

Comment: also try using strcmp() after you've confirmed the strings really are identical as above.  (hint you may need trim() :) )

Comment: @jeroen Thanks, I forgot that it is a custom made API, so I get one hell of an API

Answer (score -6):

Try This Code

```
if($_SESSION['user']['email_activation'] === $functions->getMotto($_SESSION['user']['username']))
{
    echo "Works";
}
else
{
    echo "Doesnt work";
}
```

Thanks.